# Possible Facebook documentation error that stops swift code from compiling?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift2

So I am following the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios) on how to add a custom login button in iOS but I am not sure if this is a documentation error or something is up with what I had written into my project. I have followed it for verbatim.

### I get errors at these lines:

```
"Extra argument in call ["public_profile", "user_friends", "email"]"

func loginButtonClicked() {
    var login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    FBSDKLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "user_friends", "email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if let result = result where error == nil && !result.isCancelled {
        // Successful login
        } else {
        // Canceled or error
        }
      }
   };
}
```

### Here below is what the rest of the ViewController looks like:

```
class LogInViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Add a custom login button to your app
        let myLoginButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        myLoginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        myLoginButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 40)
        myLoginButton.center = self.view.center
        myLoginButton.setTitle("My Login Button", forState: .Normal)

        // Handle cliks on the button
        myLoginButton.addTarget(self,action: "loginButtonClicked", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        // Add the button to the view
        self.view!.addSubview(myLoginButton)
    }

    // Once the button is clicked, show the login dialogue.
       func loginButtonClicked() {
    var login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    FBSDKLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "user_friends", "email"] /*Extra argument in call is here */, fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if let result = result where error == nil && !result.isCancelled {
        // Successful login
        } else {
        // Canceled or error
        }
      }
   };
}
```

TL;DR what is the exact problem and what is Xcode trying to tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error is very simple that you are not parsing Object of **FBSDKLoginManager** that you are creating with following line:

```
 var login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
```

So do the code like following:

```
 func loginButtonClicked() {
        let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        login.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in
            if let result = result where error == nil && !result.isCancelled {
            // Successful login
        } else {
            // Canceled or error
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is the way you call the `loginWithPermissions` method. You could try writing it again, let xcode autocomplete for you and then press `enter`for all the parameters, so that the right code is filled in for you.

However, this is an example of how calling the method should look like

```
loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "user_friends", "email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) -> Void in 
    if let result = result where error == nil && !result.isCancelled 
        // Successful login            
    } else {
        // Canceled or error
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you figure out your error. Let me know if it worked out :)

Comment: Well that has sort of helped me out but there are still a couple of bugs but
the line:
                ["public_profile", "user_friends", "email"]
Has the error of "Extra argument in call"

Comment: Could you update the question with the code snippet you tried? Maybe I can help you figure it out

Comment: I have amended the error with the "extra argument in call"